# Need help making a loop out of copy/pasted if statements

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I have a page which takes info from a database and displays it in a table. It does work, but it's very cumbersome.

```
//Table header here
echo "<tr><td>".$teamname."</td>";

//For Gameweek 7
if ($gw7 == "") 
{ 
    //The team has no game - highlight the cell in red
    echo "<td align='center' style='background: #FF0000'>"; 
}
    elseif (strpos($gw7,'/') !== false) 
{ 
    //The team has 2 games this week - highlight it in green
    echo "<td align='center' style='background: #00FF00'>"; 
}
else
{
    //this means the team has a single game this week - normal cell.
    echo "<td align='center'>";
}
echo $gw7."</td>";
echo "</tr>";

//for gameweek 8 to 36, the above for loop is just repeated (mostly copy/pasted)

//Table footer here
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing it? I don't like copy/pasting the same code multiple times.

The gameweeks are called `$gw7`, `$gw8`, `$gw9`, `$gw10` etc. and contain the opponents the team is facing in text format. The 7 in $gw7 represents the 7th set of games this season. They are grouped into gameweeks. Please let me know if this isn't clear.

Comment: seems pretty clear, how about just having a `$bgcolor` variable, and echoing `"<td align='center' style='background: ". $bgcolor ."'>"` after the conditions?

Comment: I'm not sure that'll simplify it much though. There are only two colors.. Green and Red... although putting it as $bgcolor means I only change it once if I ever want to change it for all.... good plan.

Comment: Sounds more like a candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create function like this

```
function gw($week) {
    //For Gameweek 7
    if ($week == "") 
    { 
        //The team has no game - highlight the cell in red
        echo "<td align='center' style='background: #FF0000'>"; 
    }
    elseif (strpos($week,'/') !== false) 
    { 
        //The team has 2 games this week - highlight it in green
        echo "<td align='center' style='background: #00FF00'>"; 
    }
    else
    {
        //this means the team has a single game this week - normal cell.
        echo "<td align='center'>";
    }
    echo $week."</td>";
}

//Table header here
echo "<tr><td>".$teamname."</td>";
gw($gw7); // call here function for $gw7 for others as well
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks what I'm after, but what is the # symbol after `gw(#gw7);` it's giving me an syntax error. Is this how you pass a variable down a function?

Comment: @Cully Sorry that was typo it should be `$` not `#`.silly mistake...now edited.

Comment: Thanks.. I thought it was some way of passing a variable down a function that I haven't seen before so I started overthinking it. It's working perfect now, thank you so much! Saves me a lot of editing later as I just have to edit the one function.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $team_array=array("team1","team2","team3","team4"); //as many teams you want
 foreach($team_array as $teamname)
 {
    $rows=getfixturesfromdb($teamname);
    //if fixtures are like $rows['gw1'],$rows['gw2']....etc
    foreach($row as  $gw)
    {
       echo "<tr><td>".$teamname."</td>";
       if ($gw == "") 
     { 
          //The team has no game - highlight the cell in red
          echo "<td align='center' style='background: #FF0000'>"; 
     }
         elseif (strpos($gw,'/') !== false) 
     { 
        //The team has 2 games this week - highlight it in green
        echo "<td align='center' style='background: #00FF00'>"; 
      }
        else
      {
         //this means the team has a single game this week - normal cell.
         echo "<td align='center'>";
      }
         echo $gw."</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the gameweeks in an array, iterate through and call the custom code for array index above 6.

```
function table_cell($color) {
    echo "<td align='center' style='background: $color'>"; 
}

//Table header here
echo "<tr><td>".$teamname."</td>";

//For Gameweek 7
if ($gw7 == "") 
{ 
    table_cell('#FF0000');
    //The team has no game - highlight the cell in red

}
    elseif (strpos($gw7,'/') !== false) 
{ 
    table_cell('#00FF00');
    //The team has 2 games this week - highlight it in green
}
else
{
    //this means the team has a single game this week - normal cell.
    echo "<td align='center'>";
}
echo $gw7."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```